# Blazor, how can I trigger an "enter key event" on an input tag to call method that accepts string parameters

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, event-handling, blazor-webassembly

I have a razor component with the following input. I currently use the "GetCourses" method to retrieve a list of courses, and everything works as expected upon button click. I would like to, however, be able to type in some string into the searchbox, and upon hitting the "enter" key, call the same "GetCourses" method. I have duplicated the "GetCourses" method and modified it to work with the @OnKeyDown event, but it does not work. In the debugger, the @OnKeyDown event is triggered with each key press, but it never binds a value to "this.inputValue." I want to capture all of the string characters in the searchbox, not one at a time, and why is it not binding?

```
   <div>
        <input type="text"
           class="searchbox"
           name="user"
           placeholder="Search by course name or course ID"
           @bind="@this.inputValue"
           @onkeydown="@GetCoursesbyKey" />
   </div>

   <span>
       <button class="searchbtn"
           @onclick="@(T => GetCourses(inputValue))">
           Search
       </button>
   </span>
```

```
@code {
    public string inputValue { get; set; }
    

    private async Task GetCoursesbyKey(KeyboardEventArgs? e)
    {
        var search = this.inputValue;

        if (e.Code == "Enter" || e.Code == "NumpadEnter")
        {
            if (search != null)
            {
                //perform some logic
            }
            else
            {
                //perform some logic
            }

            //wait on some methods here
        }
    }

    private async Task GetCourses(string search)
    {
        var search = this.inputValue;

        if (search != null)
        {
            //perform some logic
        }
        else
        {
            //perform some logic
        }

        //wait on some methods here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making this small change made the feature work perfectly. I do not have the technical analysis as to why, other than these functions accomplish what I was attempting to do.

```
   <div>
        <input type="text"
           class="searchbox"
           name="user"
           placeholder="Search by course name or course ID"
           @bind-value="@this.inputValue"
           @bind-value:event="oninput"
           @onkeydown="@GetCoursesbyKey" />
   </div>
```

Comment: as explained on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0), only `onchange` event works the way your OP is. Other DOM events need `@bind-value:event` to work.